# VLOOKUP not working when referencing cell

Tags: excel-formula

I am using VLOOKUP like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(K4,'Odds Scale'!$I$4:$J$84,2,FALSE)
```

Cell K4 is a formula that results in 0.15

The VLOOKUP fails with code #N/A

When I type 0.15 into cell K4 directly the VLOOKUP returns the correct result. It only fails when a formula calculates the cell to 0.15.

I have done VLOOKUP with cells that have formulas in them before so this should work. What is my issue here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K4 is returning a value and excel is only showing the first two decimal places.  The actual value in K4 may be .148909879 or something like that, which when displayed to only two decimals is `.15`.

Try rounding the number in K4 to two decimals in the VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(ROUND(K4,2),'Odds Scale'!$I$4:$J$84,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The data that was actually rounded to two decimals was the data in my array not in K4. Thanks for getting me in the right direction!